# GWT getting path of the application

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT application which when I deploy locally homepage after running the application is  localhost:8888/myapp.html but when we deploy it to the server, after the application running its homepage is 107.20.239.198:8080/myapp/myapp.html.

Now all the relating paths my application fail. Places where I require the exact path, I cant get that. As now the path is different. For example when I click in a particular widget in my application -> It redirects to the path '/# + "place no.1" + "place no.2" '

But now it fails when deployed on the server as now it requires the path -> '/myapp/# + "place no.1" + "place no.2" '.

So how can I make it generic, so that I can handle both the conditions.

Can anyone help me with this ?

P.S. I hope I am able to express my problem well, else you can comment it so that I can explain it better.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to get my gwt app path on server to access files on server. 
I tried ServletContext.getRealPath() but couldn't resolve it (getting an error about calling not static method!).
I also get tomcat UnsatisfiedLinkError on either GWT.getModuleBaseUrl() or GWT.getHostPageBaseUrl().

Can I know if you have found any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your local url as you mentioned above, it looks like you are running it on `AppEngine`'s server. Better you deploy your application on `Tomcat` first on your local. And make sure everything is working fine. These are the few methods which you can use to get the `relative/absolute urls` when your application starts up.

```
GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(); GWT.getModuleBaseURL(); GWT.getModuleName();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I use as you mentioned I get this error : 

com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.getModuleName()Ljava/lang/String;
RequestURI=/***Servlet Caused by:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.getModuleName()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: hope you are using these methods at client side and appending the desired resource path along with the output of above method. You can choose any one method from above, to choose just `Sysout` the output of the method to see what it returns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, 
I get tomcat UnsatisfiedLinkError on either GWT.getModuleBaseUrl() or GWT.getHostPageBaseUrl().
What am I doing wrong?

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.getModuleBaseURL()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: @Ehsan which browser are you using.. These methods must be called within `client` package. you can call it in `shared` package also only if that is being executed at client side. By client side I mean through browser.
The `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is coming because you are trying to run it at server side. Internally `GWT.getHostPageBaseURL();` will call the native javascript methods of the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response pratikabu.
I think my problem is that I am calling it on the server.
But is there any method for server side?

Answer (score 1):

You should use relative paths in your application, relative to your context. Using `request.getContextPath()` you will be able to obtain the correct context path. But if you will use "/" in your code, you will always refer to your context path, regardless on what is the context. So to create a link to a internal page you will use /internal.html. On your local machine will be transformed to localhost:8888/internal.html but on server it will be: 107.20.239.198:8080/myapp/internal.html.

Comment: But I am inside a presenter class so how can I access the HttpRequest ?

Comment: You should use the request.getContextPath(), and the methods that @pratikabu mentioned only when you would like to obtain/present the url. I was suggesting that you should use relative paths to your context. You don't need the path to redirect something to another internal page, if you are referring to it like /anotherPage.html. Instead building the action with '/# + "place no.1" + "place no.2" ' you should try: '/ + "place no.1" '

Comment: I am redirecting to a place and not .html page, so I have to construct my URL like that only, and I cant use request.getContextPath(), as I am in a presenter class  :(

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Anuj Kulkarni you should really use relative path because otherwise you will always get these Problems. But I had 1 particular Problem where I couldn't do this. So if you like you can use:

```
if (!GWT.isProdMode())
```

Here you can define different urls for your development environment and deployment.
But if you use this more than once in your code then it does mean you are doing something wrong.