# Gwt servlet fails on tomcat

Tags: servlets, gwt, jasper-reports

i can reach my Servlet locally in jetty (run as googlewebtoolkit),

but when i deploy my app in Tomcat like

> 192.0.1.23:8080/test/servlet

and trying to run it, it shows me nothing

this is my File web.xml:

```
<servlet>  
 <servlet-name>PrintReport</servlet-name>  
 <servlet-class>com.testre.test.server.PrintReport</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
 <servlet-name>PrintReport</servlet-name>  
 <url-pattern>/test/servlet</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

my servsided file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager;

public class PrintReport extends HttpServlet {  


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {

        HashMap hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put("tset", "test");

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://test;instanceName=test;databaseName=test";
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "accenon", "accenon");

        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("test.jrxml","tes.jasper");
        bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf("tset.jasper", hm, conn);
        sendPDF(response, bytes, "report.pdf");         

    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

        void sendPDF(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] bytes, String name) throws IOException
    {
        ServletOutputStream stream = null;

        stream = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + name);
        response.setContentLength((int) bytes.length);
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: What exception or error code are your getting?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /test/servlet

Comment: What is the name of `war` that you have placed under tomcat server.

Comment: Try with `192.0.1.23:8080/war_name/test/servlet`

Comment: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\test\war <----

Comment: That's wrong you have to place content of war folder under test folder

Comment: Oh ok i put the contetnt in my test folder and tried ---> 192.0.1.23:8080/test/servlet what i get now is a whitescreen lol

Comment: seem like he found the servlet

Comment: That's a good news...

Comment: That's the contract of `Tomcat` server to place the `war` under `webapps` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed the war at incorrect location.

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\test\war
```

Place all the content of `war` folder directly under `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\test` folder and remove extra `war` folder.

For more info have a look at [Developing a Web Appliction on Tomcat](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/tomcat/index.html)

Comment: ok thx for the help sp far , do u know how i get the absolute path : GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"/"GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"/"+GWT.getModuleName()+"test.jrxml"  <--- will this work before i try to compile this

Comment: Have a look at [GWT - RPC - get servlet absolute path to make dir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017343/gwt-rpc-get-servlet-absolute-path-to-make-dir)

Comment: Read [GWT getting path of the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209121/gwt-getting-path-of-the-application)